# How to update multiple rows with limit with concurrency in mind?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

I have a MongoDB database that I use as a queueing system. It used accross multiple servers that each runs multiple instances of the code.

Until now, I was using `find_one_and_delete` to get the next item pending, but I recently had the misfortune that this function is pretty resource intensive, and when the collection is reaching 100k entries, MongoDB slows down a lot and takes seconds to respond.

Instead of trying to get ONE entry, I'd like to have way to retrieve X items on that collection by ensuring there are no concurrency conflicts.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, update_many doesn't include a `limit`.

---

So far, here's what I came up with :

1. Update ALL the pending items with a unique ID (uuid)
2. Find the next X items that have that uuid, save them locally and delete them on the queue
3. Update all the other items with uuid to set at None (release them).

It's **not** great, but in my situation, it fixed the issue and looks like it worked correctly.

What I'm asking here is if there is a way to do that, in a faster (using `limit` on update_many) and concurrency-oriented way with MongoDB?

Comment: Another direction - use multiple data bases. Use a well tuned and dedicated instance of Maria Db for this? https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html have used. Works great as long as dev and ops team are open and can use a bit of automation and tools to get their job done, so can handle 2x data base with ease.

Comment: i have C# implementation of what you want.do you interest ?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth to try Mongodb Transactions as concurrency-safe mechanism.

- Create session with transaction
- Retrieve X records, `collection.find().limit(X)`
- Remove X records, `collection.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: [IDs] } })`
- Commit transaction and close session

More info about transactions here

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html

Comment: Thank you, I have given you the bounty.

Comment: Wohoo, it's my first ever bounty here :)) Thanks a lot, hope the answer was helpful to you

Comment: It was :) Thank you!

Comment: One crucial point to take into consideration, this only works if the MongoDB is on sharded or replicat set! Otherwise, transactions don't work :/

Comment: That's interesting, seems they have such restriction. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know which keys are required for querying most of the times in system, you can create a session pass the query directly in deleteMany and commit the transaction.

This will be fast as now you do not have to iterate on docs to fetch mongoids or identify which records to be deleted Mongo will do it for you.